# Magento 2 Product import to store id 0

Tags: magento2, product, import, programmatically

I'm really struggling getting a simple product import to work on Magento 2. I've done this several times in ver 1.x without trouble, but M2 is driving me crazy

The code should be simple

```
    $product = $this->productFactory->create();
    $product->setTypeId($document->product_type);
    $product->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId);
    $product->setVisisbility(4);
    $product->setUrlKey($queue->getSku());
    $product->setWebsiteIds($arrAllStores);
    $product->setStockData([
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
        'manage_stock' => 0, //manage stock
        'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
        'qty' => 100 //qty
        ]
    );
    foreach ($product_attributes as $key => $attr) {
        $product->setData($key, $attr);
    }
    $product->save();
```

Problem is, that Magento randomly decides in what store view it would like to strore the various attributes.

So I end up only having two values stored in store 0 while most others are set to store id 2 (which is the default frontend view). I'm running the code in admin, so this shouldn't happen. In my opinion it shouldn't happen at all. It should only be saved on store view level if specifically requested, anything else should be stored in view 0.

I've been trying adaptions of "setCurrentStore" like

```
$this->objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->setCurrentStore(0);
```

But they have no effect.

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. A framework should make things simpler, but in Magento it is always the opposite. I'm doing my best to follow guidelines, but this is just motivating me to write directly to the DB, because that way at least things work the way they should.

Comment: I've just stumbled across this issue as well - is this happening on CE or EE?

Comment: It's happening on CE, but probably is no different in EE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issue and found that the problem goes away when you use the ProductRepositoryInterface to perform the save (which is now the recommended way to do it). I also developed my problematic code against 2.0 so I needed to make the same change, and my store scoping is now correct. When I revert back to the deprecated model save method it throws things into a different store_id like you've reported.

To solve the problem in your case, inject an instance of ProductRepositoryInterface into your class and then replace:

```
$product->save();
```

with this:

```
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

Not sure why the old save method is now buggy, but it looks like they've deprecated it for a good reason.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. Makes you wonder why Varien insists on making things more complicated all the time.

Comment: this answere does not having the correct effekt. you have to set the current store in constructor so the product will load and save correctly. look at answere from @Sébastien Trottier

Answer (score 5):

```
setCurrentStore(0)
```

sets the current store to the default store (which can be different than 0 depending of context) as of Magento 2.1.2.

Use:

```
setCurrentStore('admin')
```

to set the current store to store ID 0, which is using 'admin' as store code.

Comment: where can i change this value?

Comment: @zus change it in the constructor. "$this->objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->setCurrentStore(0);"  P.S this should be the correct answere